# How can you help Solana make it from Private to Public Beta? And preparing for an initial Pro-Tem Moderator Election!

Tags: discussion, beta, announcements, election

We’re 2 weeks into the private beta for Solana Stack Exchange — around halfway through the site's private beta phase — so I thought it'd be a good time to cover 2 topics to get you thinking about the site's future:

1. How can you help the site make it from Private to Public Beta?
2. Your initial Pro-Tem Moderator Election, if you make it into Public Beta!

---

### So what can you do to help the Solana site make it to public Beta?

- **Read through the help center:** We have [a comprehensive help center](https://solana.stackexchange.com/help) with articles explaining how most of our system works. We suggest you go through some of the articles there — especially if you're new to the Stack Exchange network.
- **Vote early, vote often:** Voting is how good content gets recognized, wrong or incoherent content is signaled, and how a community of editors, closers, stewards, and moderators comes into existence in the SE network. Read more [in this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/19/vote-early-vote-often/) and [in this FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130046/208518), and be careful not to engage in [voting fraud](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/208518) or [sock-puppeting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/208518).
- **Discuss what your site is about on Meta:** [The Essential Questions of Every Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223674/208518) is a community-curated revised version of an earlier blog post that lists a few of the most important things new communities should be discussing in Meta. You should be making use of your Meta site to discuss things like:

  - Are questions about [subject] on- or off-topic?
  - What should our documentation contain?
  - How should we tag questions about [subject]?
  - What's the site's 'elevator pitch'?
  - How do we promote our site?
- **Edit, close, or delete content:** Sometimes questions or answers need a little tweak, either because they have typos or because they don't quite fit the site's scope without some edits; [you should help out by editing those posts](https://solana.stackexchange.com/help/editing). Sometimes questions are beyond being salvageable, though, and you should instead be [closing](https://solana.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) or [deleting](https://solana.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions) them.
- **Invite fellow experts to the site:** There's an "invite fellow experts" box on the site's right sidebar – make use of it!
- **Start building guidance for tags:** Tags are an important way to sort content in our sites, and having the proper guidance on how tags should be used is essential to ensure content is properly tagged. Read more [here about tagging](https://solana.stackexchange.com/help/tagging), and [here about providing tag guidance](https://solana.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts).

---

### Initial Pro-Tem Moderator Election: Community Interest Check

Now that we've covered what you can do to help the site move into Public Beta, let's cover what comes next if it does: the election to choose your first pro-tem moderators.

#### What does it take to be a Moderator?

Prior to 2018, [pro-tem moderators would be picked by staff](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/), and the Community Management team would look for users who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).
- Have an eye for content that should be flagged, closed or removed and act on that within the expectations of the community and Stack Exchange generally.

#### Electing your moderators

In 2018, however, we started experimenting with hosting elections for beta sites to choose their pro-tem moderators, in addition to the community-elected moderators in sites not in Beta, in the rest of the network. The process is mostly the same, but if you’re interested in the full details, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections).

In accordance with that, I’m here today to pre-announce this site’s first pro-tem election and invite users interested in nominating to state their intention to do so here. Additionally, if you feel someone would be a good fit as a moderator on this site, feel free to use an answer to this question to support them and encourage them to run. The timeline:

- Starting on the Monday following the site moving into Public Beta (week 1), users can nominate themselves in the election page. Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On the following Monday (week 2), if there are 4 or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period there are still less than 4 candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on the following Tuesday (week 3) (or the one after that, on week 4, if we need to extend the nomination period).

##### NOTES:

- **This is not an official election nomination thread.** It’s just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination here.
- **This does not mean that the site has been cleared to leave Private Beta.** The dates for the election are provisional and subject to change, and the election as a whole is dependent on Solana meeting the requirements to progress from Private into Public Beta.

---

If you have any questions about the election or site lifecycle processes, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: What does pro-tem stand for?

Comment: See https://translate.google.com/?sl=la&tl=en&text=pro%20tempore&op=translate, @AllBlooming ;)

Comment: Oh thanks :-) I did take 4 years of Latin in high school (in Germany), but I shoudda  consi'd Americans abbrevving everything (even tempore) . Been living in the US for a long time now, but it seems I'm not an American thru & thru yet. Takin' it EZ tho. 

Comment: It's been about 5 days and has there been updates on us moving into the public beta?

Comment: The private beta period takes 4~5 weeks, @Ethan ;)

Comment: @JNat I meant activity today use. Are we looking like we will leave the private beta

Answer (score 1):

I hope to run for the moderator election when it opens.

These are some candidates that I also want to nominate:

- [Trent.sol](https://solana.stackexchange.com/users/36/trent-sol) (Solana-Labs): Trent has been the most active during the private beta phase of our stackexchange and is an expert on all things Solana. He has knowledge that spans writing programs to the core protocol design.
- [C.OG](https://solana.stackexchange.com/users/50/c-og) (Solana Foundation): Colin is an experienced StackOverflow user and understands Solana programs at a deep level. He has been doing a good job keeping active and editing other's posts.
- [Henry-e](https://solana.stackexchange.com/users/255/henry-e) (Anchor Expert): Henry is an Anchor expert and very helpful to the Anchor framework community on Solana. His knowledge shared across StackExchange and helpful discussion in comments has greatly improved the health of our private beta.
- [Callum-m](https://solana.stackexchange.com/users/289/callum-m) (Pointergg):  Callum has done a great job ushering new users to StackExchange as well as helping them out with their support. He is an expert at Solana and actively participates creating tutorials.
- [Steveluscher](https://solana.stackexchange.com/users/75/steveluscher) (Solana Labs): Steven is an expert of all things javascript. He actively maintains many parts of web3.js and SMS on Solana, and has a deep knowledge of the Solana ecosystem.
- [Arowana](https://solana.stackexchange.com/users/1128/arowana) (Anchor Expert): Arowana is a Solana expert and very good at all things Anchor. He knows how Solana works at a deeper level than most developers out there today. He has been very helpful during the private beta phase with answering questions and providing feedback.

Comment: To clarify: you can't nominate other users, just mention here that you think they'd make good candidates. Once the nomination period opens, they'll have to nominate themselves, if they want to.