# Leaving Private Beta, and Initial Pro-Tempore Moderator Election!

Tags: discussion, election, beta, announcements

**Congratulations! You've met the participation and engagement expectations for an active private beta site, and will be moving into public beta on August 16, 2022!**

As the Community Team watched over this site's 4 weeks of private beta, we've seen some healthy discussions take place here on Meta, as well as a high-volume of questions being asked and answered on the main site. Overall, our one area of concern is that most voting on the site seems to be undertaken by only a handful of people — it's not a showstopper, but hopefully something y'all keep an eye on. Remember [our guidance from week 2](https://solana.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15/735): **vote early, vote often!**

As we’re getting ready to wrap up the private beta for Solana Stack Exchange, that means it’s time to schedule your first pro-tem moderator election!

[On week 2 of your private beta](https://solana.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15/735), I walked you through the process and what qualities a moderator ideally has, and called out for folks to express their willingness to run in an election — which, so far, no one has done. In this post, I’m focusing on the election timeline itself.

### The timeline:

- Starting on August 22, 2022, users can nominate themselves on the [election page](https://solana.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On August 29, 2022, if there are 4 or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, the nomination period will be extended for a week. If, at the end of that extension period there are 4 or more candidates, we'll run an election; if there are 3 candidates, the Community Team will simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).)

  - **NOTE: If the election doesn't have at least valid 3 candidates at the end of the nomination phase, it will be cancelled and considered a failed election, and this site will be shut down.**
- If there is an election, we'll announce the results on meta on September 6, 2022 (or September 13, 2022, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please ask them in an answer below.

And congratulations, once again!