# How do we encourage more voting?

Tags: discussion, voting

As noted in [Leaving Private Beta, and Initial Pro-Tempore Moderator Election!](https://solana.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30/leaving-private-beta-and-initial-pro-tempore-moderator-election) :

> Overall, our one area of concern is that most voting on the site seems to be undertaken by only a handful of people — it's not a showstopper, but hopefully something y'all keep an eye on

How do we encourage more voting on good answers and questions?